# if statement to match what is in array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement, equals

I've built a function that tests if an array is empty, if it is, it sets the only object to "not available", this is for use outputting to HTML elements, rather than them being empty.

```
function checkNull(input){
    if (input === null || input === undefined || input === false || input === '' || input === ' ' || input.length === 0){
        $input = ["(not available)"];
    }
    else{
        $input = input;
    }
    return $input;
}
```

If an array of image urls happens to be empts it is set as above, how do I then test to match if the array is equal to what I have set it as?

Here's what i've tried;

```
function checkGallery($gameImageUrls){
    console.log($gameImageUrls);
    if ($gameImageUrls === ["(not available)"]){
        $('#gallery').addClass('hidden');    
    }
    else{
        generateGallery($gameImageUrls);
    }
}
```

Here's what console.log displays:

> ["(not available)"]

also tried;

```
    if ($gameImageUrls === '["(not available)"]'){
    if ($gameImageUrls === "(not available)"){
    if ($gameImageUrls === '"(not available)"'){
```

Comment: I should mention it must remain in square brackets as some other things passed to the function need to be an array for other functions, whereas this does not.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Doesn't `array.length == 0` suffice?

Comment: `$gameImageUrls.length === 1 && $gameImageUrls[0] === "(not available)"` ?

Comment: not setting it as text and using array.length works perfectly, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you will need to check the first element in array, something like this:

```
$gameImageUrls[0] === "(not available)"
```